# Replace certain variables with NA, one variable is NA

Tags: r, conditional-statements, na

What is the best function to use if I want to replace certain variables with NA based on a conditional?
[image]

If status = NA, then score_1:score_3 will be NA

tried:

```
if(df2$status == NA){
 df2$score_2 <- NA
}else{
  df2$score_2 <- df$score_2
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to find the `NA`s in 'status' and assign the columns that having 'score' as column name to `NA` in `base R`

```
i1 <- is.na(df2$Status)
df2[i1, grep("^Score_\\d+$", names(df2))] <- NA
```

---

Or an option in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df2 %>%
     mutate_at(vars(starts_with('Score')), ~ replace(., is.na(Status), NA))
```

Comment: Thank you, I keep getting the error saying that object status doesn't exist

Comment: @DanielleTravassos  In your image, it shows `Status` whiile in your code it is `status`.  R is case sensitive.  So, please change the names to the corrrect column names.  I updated the code

Comment: Hi Akrun, Thank you. It's status, and i'm still getting this message. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: @DanielleTravassos  Can you post the column names of 'df2' `colnames(df2)`.  May be there is some leading/lagging spaces

Comment: df%>%
+ mutate_at(vars(starts_with('lot_num_')), ~ replace(., is.na(flag_3), NA))
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: object 'flag_3' not found.

Comment: @DanielleTravassos What is the `packageVersion('dplyr')`.  I used `[1] ‘0.8.3’`

Comment: Maybe that's the problem. Actually the solution above worked. Now I'm trying to put on a loop and it's not working.  
for(i in 1:10){
  
  variable_4 <- paste0("lot_num_", i)
  variable_5 <- paste0("agent_", i)
  variable_6 <- paste0("flag_", i)
  
    idx <- which(is.na(df$variable_6))
    df[idx, "variable_5"] <- NA 
    df[idx, "variable_4"] <- NA     
}

Comment: @DanielleTravassos  Reasson is `df$variable_6` it should be `df[[variable_6]]`

Comment: This works wonderfully. Thank you @akrun and @Jake! I wish I could select both answers as helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by finding out which rows in the data frame are `NA` and then setting the columns in those rows to `NA`.

```
df <- data.frame(client_id = 1:4,
       Date = 1:4,
       Status = c(1, NA, 1, NA),
       Score1 = runif(4)*100,
       Score2 = runif(4)*100,
       Score3 = runif(4)*100)

idx <- is.na(df$Status)

df[idx, 4:6] <- NA

df
#>   client_id Date Status   Score1   Score2   Score3
#> 1         1    1      1 48.08677 16.62185 91.80062
#> 2         2    2     NA       NA       NA       NA
#> 3         3    3      1 14.04552 64.55724 56.45998
#> 4         4    4     NA       NA       NA       NA
```

Comment: Thank you! Will this work for df with several rows? Like 80 or 100?

Comment: Yes.  The idx will find all `NA` rows for the Status columns.

Comment: In this case I have to know the position of the variable, right? I have tons of variables I have to replace with NA and they're not in order. Should I order them first  then?

Comment: In the case of multiple variables, you will have to know by position or by name, which ones you are replacing.  @akruns answer provides a way to do so by matching column name, rather than by position.